# Remove a negative element from an array w/o array.copy

Tags: java

How can I remove negative elements from an array without making a copy of it?/moving the position of the array. Say for example, if the user filled the array, what method could I use to simply return the altered array? Would it be possible to just omit the elements using an if statement?

Comment: What do you want to do net with your array ?

Comment: If you have stored Integer objects in the array, make them null if the Integer is negative

Comment: You can't change the size of an array, to return a different size you need to return a copy.

Comment: Actually you can shrink an array with a hack but don't do this in production.

Answer (score 4):

If you simply want to remove all the negative elements in the `Array` you can do:

```
arr = Arrays.stream(arr).filter(e -> e >= 0).toArray();
```

Where `arr` is your `Array`

Comment: This will also remove 0, which isn't a negative value. Though OP's use case is unclear.